# Completely uninstall, remove, delete any reference to Coda 2 by Panic!

Tags: applications, macos, coda, ide

How do I completely remove Coda 2 by Panic!? I love the app, and have been using it for years, however I did a fresh install on a new mac, and had it all set up, then I went to add some plugins and it screwed it up somehow. None of my preferences are stored, none of my ssl's are stored. I can't reconfigure the app, cause when I go into the preferences every time it crashes as soon as I close the pane out.

All in all I know the app works well, but it seems theres a glicth in it somewhere that can only possibly be resolved by completely removing it.

I have dragged it from the application folder to the trash..
I removed the Coda 2 folder from `Users/username/Library/Application\ Support/Coda\ 2/`

and I reinstalled it, problem here is same issues occur again, I didn't install any plugins so its just the app. Now I know there is also something storing more data somewhere. Since the install didn't show the app in its default state which is large buttons at the top, and I noticed going into the preference pane that there was some non default options checked as well. So the two things I did to remove it didn't completely remove it.

And since Apple appears to think that no one will ever uninstall anything and thusly doesn't have a method tried and true to uninstall anything I am at a loss. Any ideas how I can remove everything to this app, and get it essentially reset to as if it was never installed before so when I install it again thats the state I get?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you probably just need to nuke your user preferences.

Open terminal and past this command (make a backup of the Mac if you don't trust this):

```
defaults delete com.panic.coda2
```

You can also make a brand new user on the Mac and try opening coda there to double check it's not some other file somewhere or it it's really something out of your user home folder.

- [Isolating an issue by using another user account](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204772)